# populate from diff tables based on condition

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to join 3 tables in a view; here is the situation:
    I have 3 tables....
    first one is [ADM_Panels] that contain information of panels with
    columns:panel_id, panel_number, YearID
    second one is [ADM_PanelsDtl] with
    columns: [panel_id], [pnlmember_id]
I have another table called "GEN_Years" with 2 columns 
    table 3: [GEN_Years]
    columns:[YearID] ,[Year]

I tried some thing like this but my select statement should return 2 different tables

```
SELECT YearID,count(pnlmember_id) Reviewer FROM [ADM_PanelsDtl] join [ADM_Panels] 
on [ADM_PanelsDtl].[panel_id]=[ADM_Panels].[panel_id]group by YearID

select YearID,count([panel_id])Panel from dbo.ADM_Panels group by YearID
```

But i want to show my result in a table with fields

```
[YearID], [Year], count(pnlmember_id), count([panel_id])Panel
```

by joining the above 3 tables. Any solution on how to do it?

I don't want to use temporary table, I just want want to join these tables

Answer (score 1):

May be lyk this

```
SELECT A.[YearID], c.[Year], a.Reviewer, B.Panel
FROM   (SELECT YearID,
               Count(pnlmember_id) Reviewer
        FROM   [ADM_PanelsDtl]
               JOIN [ADM_Panels]
                 ON [ADM_PanelsDtl].[panel_id] = [ADM_Panels].[panel_id]
        GROUP  BY YearID) A
       JOIN (SELECT YearID,
                    Count([panel_id])Panel
             FROM   dbo.ADM_Panels
             GROUP  BY YearID) B 
         ON a.YearID = b.YearID join GEN_Years c on a.YearID = c.YearID
```

Comment: yaa...its working properly...thanks Pradeep.i want to show year